# Cannot get speed for simple OpenMP parallel for loop

Tags: openmp, parallel.for

This is my first try on OpenMP, but cannot get speedup on it. The machine is Linux amd_64. 
I coded the following code:

```
printf ("nt = %d\n", nt);
omp_set_num_threads(nt);

int i, j, s;
#pragma omp parallel for private(j,s)
for (i=0; i<10000; i++)
{
   for (j=0; j<100000; j++)
   {
      s++;
   }
}


And the compile with
g++ tempomp.cpp -o tomp -lgomp

And run it with different nthreads, no speedup:

nt = 1
elapsed time =2.670000

nt = 2
elapsed time =2.670000

nt = 12
elapsed time =2.670000
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to add the flag `-fopenmp` to your compiler:

```
 g++ tempomp.cpp -o tomp -lgomp -fopenmp
```

When `-fopenmp` is used, the compiler will generate parallel code
based on the OpenMP directives encountered.
`-lgomp` loads libraries of the Gnu OpenMP Project.

How many cores do your machine have?